# What's the difference between "string" .$var and "string $var" in php?

Tags: php, variables

In preparing MySQL statements in PHP, I came across lines of codes like this:

```
$somequery = "some query '$var'";
```

Where `$var` is a variable containing a string.

What is the difference with the statement using the string concatenating operator `.`?

```
$somequery = "some query " . $var;
```

The result string is actually the same. If there is any difference, when should I use the one over the other?

Comment: The resulting strings shouldn't be exactly the same: you have additional single quotes in one of them.... but in general as an answer to your question, __readability__

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes Eh, not necessarily. And the performance of each has changed drastically over the years.

Comment: @Niels - micro-optimisation unless you're working with incredibly long strings when there's more memory overhead in concatenation

Comment: Third option (and my favourite) - [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf)

Comment: @Niels so... you save a nanosecond or two. Connecting to the database or reading a file takes a hundred times as long. What real-world relevance does the difference have in *any* scenario?

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes Interesting test. Perhaps you want to put that in an answer?

Comment: A question about your usage scenario: If you are *"preparing"* a statement, as you say, then why are you *concatenating* a string variable? Wouldn't you use a placeholder then anyway?

Comment: @Niels - My original answer still stands, readability matter more than millisecond micro-optimisation

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes Mentioning it. Fine with me because it is a difference. Telling people they should do it to shave of two milliseconds is micro optimization of the worst kind. {insert-college-freshman-meme-here}

Comment: @mario, No I do not need to prepare the statement, $var is not a user's input. I wanted to know the difference generally.

Comment: "and use the faster approach in framework code."

Comment: @mario This isn't really about SQL statements, it's about interpolating variables in strings. Save that tired battle for another thread.

Comment: Regarding performance, Rasmus posted on Twitter about this some time back (not sure how to link in context so click each in turn): https://twitter.com/rasmus/status/207811953593303040 https://twitter.com/rasmus/status/207814295508090880 https://twitter.com/rasmus/status/207817187266805762 https://twitter.com/rasmus/status/207818331741356032 https://twitter.com/rasmus/status/207819016386002944

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference in the output. The performance differences are negligible. Use whichever one looks nicer to you. Some prefer concatenation because syntax highlighters like it.

Answer (score 0):

The value is the same, but just use one which will make your code easy to read or debug by yourself or by others you have given permission to!